# TeamCity is replacing a specific phrase with asterisks

Tags: teamcity

We've just started having issues with TeamCity replacing a certain text phrase (the company name) with asterisks throughout the build process (specifically when running Powershell steps.

[image: Powershell build step]

You can see here that we are pulling from github repo that contains the text, as well as a branch that contains the text and it's replacing it with `*******`.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case? It's causing builds to fail.

Running TC 2018.1.1

Comment: that's because those parts matches with properties marked as a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the TeamCity want to protect your password in the build log.

As said [@daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett), when you have a **password** parameter with the value which matches the company name then TC will replace it with asterisks

Comment: AS far as I can tell, we don't have any config/system/env password parameters, but looking through the build parameters, it looks like it could be `system.teamcity.auth.password`. I *think* this is the build agent password (as we use cloud azure agents)

Comment: Awesome. It turns out it was the passphrase for our SSH key (I know not ideal, but these things happen). Once I changed the SSH key passphrase & updated all VCS roots & Build Features (SSH Agent), it no longer masks the text. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. I think it's a great feature. it allows hiding all things which can be used in the illegal operations.